# Hide friends offline in the update made today

Tags: steam

In the old steam interface, we could hide our offline friends in the list.
Is there a way to do it in the new interface?
I have too many I have to look for those who are online is horrible, could you help me?
[image: steamList]

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Are you looking in your friends list? Are you using the new Steam beta?

Comment: Yes it's my friend list on the new Steam Beta there is no filter it make me crazy, I have a huge friend list :/

Comment: Could you take a screenshot?

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I edit my post, see the people who are on grey ? They are offline and I want to hide them because there is a lot and I have to scroll to find some ...

Comment: In that screenshot, what is CDI?

Comment: it corresponds to a category of friends, I have another one that includes all my team etc. It's a way of "tidy up" to better find them.

Comment: looks like it's not possible at the moment, there is a link 'beta feedback' in lower part of window - that's your chance to request this missing feature

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like now it's possible, they've added option to hide friends in categories:

[image]

This menu is available from 'Manage friend list settings' cogwheel right above the friends list.